# can only concentrate list (not "int") to list when adding arrays together

Tags: python, integer

I have a project where i have to add the exam points of a student to the total of the class and then find the class average.

````
AllStudents = []
Sum = 0
ClassSum = []
Total = []
for x in range(2):
    name = input("enter student name: ")

    Student = []
    Student.append(name)

    StudentPoint1 = int(input("points for test 1: "))
    if StudentPoint1 > 20:
        print("Test 1 score invalid, should be less than 20")

    StudentPoint2 = int(input("points for test 2: "))
    if StudentPoint2 > 25:
        print("Test 2 score invalid, should be less than 25")

    StudentPoint3 = int(input("points for test 3: "))
    if StudentPoint1 > 35:
        print("Test 3 score invalid, should be less than 35")

    Student.append(StudentPoint1)
    Student.append(StudentPoint2)
    Student.append(StudentPoint3)

    Sum = StudentPoint1 + StudentPoint2 + StudentPoint3
    Total.append(Sum)
    ClassSum.append(Total + Sum)

    AllStudents.append(Student)
print(ClassSum)
print(AllStudents)```
````

on the line where it says ClassSum.append(Total + Sum) i get the error "can only concentrate list (not "int") to list"

Comment: What does Total and ClassSum represents ?

Comment: `Total` is a list whereas `Sum` is int.

Comment: The problem here is that `Total` is a list, and you cant add a number to a list (the same way you cant answer the question "What is 4 + table?"), they are 2 different types of information, and cant be added together.

Seeing as `Total` is a list of each individual student's `Sum`, do you mind to explain what exactly `ClassSum` is meant to represent?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you want to do but i think increment with '+=' is better than append to a list. I made this code if it can help:

```
AllStudents = []
Sum = 0
ClassSum = 0
Total = []
for x in range(2):
    name = input("enter student name: ")

    Student = []
    Student.append(name)

    StudentPoint1 = int(input("points for test 1: "))
    if StudentPoint1 > 20:
        print("Test 1 score invalid, should be less than 20")

    StudentPoint2 = int(input("points for test 2: "))
    if StudentPoint2 > 25:
        print("Test 2 score invalid, should be less than 25")

    StudentPoint3 = int(input("points for test 3: "))
    if StudentPoint1 > 35:
        print("Test 3 score invalid, should be less than 35")

    Student.append(StudentPoint1)
    Student.append(StudentPoint2)
    Student.append(StudentPoint3)

    Sum = StudentPoint1 + StudentPoint2 + StudentPoint3
    ClassSum+=Sum

    AllStudents.append(name)

print(ClassSum)
print(AllStudents)
print(f'Average is {ClassSum/len(AllStudents)}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ClassSum.append(sum(Total))
```

You can't perform addition with an integer and list as operands. Also why would you try adding `Sum` to `Total` when `Total` already has `Sum` as its element.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to sum a list and an integer variable if you are trying to add sum for each student then you need to access using the list indices.
`ClassSum.append(Total[x] + Sum)`